# Remapping keys in a Mac in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, macbook

So I have an old MacBook 2.1, and I created a script to:

-make the right super key="menu" key;

-make the pseudo-numeric-keyboard-enter="Alt Gr";

-make the "eject"=Delete

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = Menu"
xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
xmodmap -e "keycode 169 = Delete"
```

and it works as long as the computer is awake. How can I make it permanent?

Also, when I   added the last line, the "eject" works once (deletes 1 character) but then the keys stop working as I coded them. How can I change it?

--
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use CompizConfig Settings Manager to run commands when a key is pressed. If you know a command to simulate those keys, you can assign it to a key under `Commands>Commands` and then `Commands>Key Bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the commands in your $HOME/.Xmodmap file:

```
keycode 104 = ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 169 = Delete
keycode 134 = Menu
```

Logout, login, that is!